# what could be the reason for a vertex for not moving?

Tags: modeling, vertices

i've been modelling and everything was good and for some reason when trying to adjust the model one of the vertices does not move. every other vertice is moving just fine... what could be the problem? (the snap magnet is turned off) and how can i solve it?
thank you!

[image]

Comment: screenshot plz what is missing

Comment: It can be on the Mirror plane of the Mirror modifier and as Clipping is enabled it is sticked to one place along X (in your case) axis. Disable modifier temporarily to check if this is the case. If yes then I'd suggest not moving it along X axis from where it is

Comment: Mr Zak, please enter your comments with solution as an answer so everybody can easily see the problem is solved :)

Comment: @JanKadeřábek you or anyone else are welcome to post the answer, only elaborate it a bit

Comment: [Don't look @bertmoog](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/can-a-punishment-be-implemented-for-using-the-word-vertice-in-a-q-a?s=2|10.8150)

Comment: maybe if u attach your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?ref=be-community-add-2 maybe we can notice whats going wrong